# What is the correct syntax to suppress specific checkstyle rules on certain files?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using **Maven 3** and **Checkstyle 2.9.1** in my **java** project and I have a common checkstyle configuration that we're using in several other projects as well. To avoid copying and editing that configuration file into my own project I use a **suppressions file** to disable all checks in some packages (generated code).

**Now I want to suppress specific rules in all files.**

This is my suppressions file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="my[\\/]generated[\\/]code[\\/]package" checks="."/>
    <suppress files=".*\\.java$" checks="IndentationCheck"/>
    <suppress files=".*\\.java$" checks="LineLengthCheck"/>
    <suppress files=".*\\.java$" checks="ExplicitInitializationCheck"/>
    <suppress files=".*\\.java$" checks="MemberNameCheck"/>
</suppressions>
```

This is my POM:

```
...
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${checkstyle.ruleset}</configLocation>
                <suppressionsLocation>${checkstyle.suppressions}</suppressionsLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm then calling

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
```

to generate the reports, but the suppressed warnings are still in there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to build a working suppressions file for my checkstyle configuration.

My *original problem* was with the regex, so instead of `files=".*\\.java$"` I'm now using `files="."` to suppress special checks on all files. I also suppress all checks on certain files.

Here are some examples from my suppressions file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <!-- suppress certain checks on all files in a package -->
    <suppress files="my[\\/]super[\\/]package[\\/]name" checks="ModifierOrderCheck|NeedBracesCheck|MagicNumberCheck"/>
    <!-- suppress all checks on all files in a package -->
    <suppress files="another[\\/]super[\\/]package[\\/]of[\\/]mine" checks=".*"/>
    <!-- suppress certain checks on all files -->
    <suppress files="." checks="IndentationCheck"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="LineLengthCheck"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="ExplicitInitializationCheck"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="MemberNameCheck"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="FinalClassCheck"/>
</suppressions>
```

If you need help with the **Maven** part of the configuration, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879272/834/) of @Mawia.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Instead of doing

```
<suppressionsLocation>${checkstyle.suppressions}</suppressionsLocation>
```

I put this in ${checkstyle.ruleset} (which I assume is your xml file for check  style)

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${checkstyle.suppressions}" />
</module>
```

And my ${checkstyle.suppressions} has

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="package-info.java" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
    <suppress files="SomeClass.java" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
</suppressions>
```

Comment: Well, the suppressions file is recognized and used. But the actual suppression wasn't working. I found the solution, but don't have the sourcecode with me today. I'll update my question on monday.

Comment: ${checkstyle.ruleset} and ${checkstyle.suppressions}  what goes in these two ?